# AspNetCore OData Function with Parameter has no metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

We're building out an OData API using AspNetCore v3.1, EF Core and ODataCore v7. When adding a function without a paramter it works perfectly giving back the @odata.context and values, but once we add in a parameter it breaks and only returns an array of strings.

I have tried adding as an unbound, then bound. I've tried `[ODataRoutePrefix]` just in case. If I remove the property and hard code a value then I get back the OData wrapper with metadata. Once I add it back in it doesn't work. Not sure why it hates the property. I've also tried the property in camelCase, PascalCase. I've tried the routing with `(measurementYear={measurementYear})`, `({measurementYear})` and neither work. I've tried it as an `[FromODataUri]` and that doesn't work. I am at wits end to get this metadata and solve my OData routing woes!

EdmModel:

```
var getDomainDescriptions = builder.EntitySet<Measure>()
    .Collection
    .Function("GetDomainDescriptions")
    .ReturnsCollection<string>();

getDomainDescriptions.Parameter<string>("measurementYear").Required();
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)] // For Swagger to work
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class MeasuresController : ODataController
{
    /// Other code
    
    [HttpGet("GetDomainDescriptions(measurementYear={measurementYear})")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult<string> GetDomainDescriptions(string measurementYear)
    {
        var dd = _context.Measure.Where(m => m.MeasurementYear == measurementYear).GroupBy(g => g.DomainDescription).Select(grp => grp.Key);

        return Ok(dd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but try defining the route as `GetDomainDescriptions/measurementYear({measurementYear})`.

Comment: Just tried that and no go, but thanks.